# Building app with Xenomai (linux)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, xenomai

I am new to Xenomai and Linux and I have a problem for building app with many files. I have a folder which contains some of .c and .h
files.

I have this xenomai makefile sample which work if I have only one file.

```
XENO_CONFIG := PATH_TO_XENO_CONFIG
CFLAGS := $(shell $(XENO_CONFIG) --cobalt --cflags)
LDFLAGS := $(shell $(XENO_CONFIG) --cobalt --ldflags)
CC := $(shell $(XENO_CONFIG) --cc)

EXECUTABLE := cobalt_app

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

%: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

No I want to change it to use it with many files. Do you have any ideas ? I plan to to use the wildcard variables but I don't know how.